# Display hosts alive with fping

Tags: linux

I am using fping to show the address ip of hosts alive like this:
Code:

```
fping -A -d -a -q -g  192.168.1.0/24>file.txt
```

the result is:

```
box.home (192.168.1.1)
set-top-box41.home (192.168.1.10)
pc38.home (192.168.1.11)
pc43.home (192.168.1.12)
pc39.home (192.168.1.15)
```

My problem is that this command display this hosts and take about 28s to stop running.I don't know how can i do to stop this command after it display the hosts.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can speedup your network scan by adding additional flags:

```
fping -A -d -a -q -g -a -i 1 -r 0 192.168.1.0/24
```

> −i n
>   The minimum amount of time (in milliseconds) between sending a ping packet to any target (default is 25).
>
> −r n
>   Retry limit (default 3). This is the number of times an attempt at pinging a target will be made, not including the first try.

You need to be root if `n` < 10.