# Linux shell (sh) CLI test if ping successful

Tags: linux, networking, command-line-interface, sh, ping

How to wire linux shell (sh) script to test with `ping` if host is reachable?
I guess there could be solution that uses grep but maybe `ping` provides that option by itself?

I am more into getting a whitelisting a successful ping operation that reached the host then checking if there was any error. I don't care about the reason of `ping` not succeeding in reaching a host.

I would like to limit ping attempts count and maximum amount of time to reach the host so the script does not waits too long for ping trying to reach a host.

Comment: the easiest way is use fping command, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301094/display-hosts-alive-with-fping

Comment: @Labradorcode unlucky I don't have the fping on the machine, and don't want to install it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt=$(date +%d)

cksize=50

echo "Start $(date)"

while IFS= read -r sn    
do

  echo "*************************************************"
  echo "Begin checking NODES client: $sn"

  if ping -c 1 "$sn" -i 5 > /dev/null
  then  
    echo "$sn   node up"
  else
    echo "$sn   node down"
  fi 
done < server_list
```

Comment: Works well, however I needed to add to the `ping` command `2>/dev/null` to suppress `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted` that was printed for some of the host's IP.

Answer (score 1):

```
parallel -j0 --timeout 15 'ping -c 5 -i 0.2 {} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo {} up || echo {} down' ::: freenetproject.org debian.org no-such.domain {1..254}.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. It will do it in parallel for all hosts.

```
#!/bin/bash

for server in 'google.com' 'github.com' 'fakeserver.com'
do
    { ping -o "$server" &>/dev/null && echo "$server is UP"  || echo "$server is DOWN" ; } &
done
wait
```

Regards!

Comment: `ping -o` gives `ping: invalid option -- 'o'`.